JS Express on Azure VM: suspicious requests?
I've set up an Azure VM and am running an express application in vscode from there.
The application is used by a Teams app I'm developing. A handful of people are trying out the app.
Recently, I've added some request logging to see how much traffic I'm getting and to find out at what time crashes happen, approximately. However, I've been getting strange requests;
A long list of GET requests to variations of 'main.html' and 'default.asp', but also stranger directories
I'm only getting about 20 requests from teams users per day, and my teams app definitely doesn't send out these kinds of requests.
I've also seen requests made to solr/admin/cores and /ui/authentication specifically, I don't like the sound of that.
Is this harmless, like a webscraper or something, or should I be cautious about this? The express app only handles 3 specific requests (none of the ones in the image).
I'm planning to create an IIS server on the VM and move the application on there, would my security situation change in any way for these types of messages?
I've set the redirect rules to redirect all traffic to the express index file, any incoming request should only be able to attempt stuff there.
I'm no expert on Express, so if there are any default commands that allow you to do anything else outside of the routing methods I made, I'd be glad to know!

What you're seeing is a scan for common vulnerabilities and misconfigurations which can be exploited.
Whenever you make a common service available, especially TCP 80 (HTTP) or TCP 443 (HTTPS), you should expect to receive many requests from malicious actors or worms, trying to find anything they can infiltrate to find things of potential value.
There isn't enough space here for me to explain all of the protective measures you should take to protect node. Luckily, Microsoft have a solution in Azure which can significantly enhance security with minimal steps.
Every Web Server exposed to the internet should have a Web Application Firewall which the Web requests come in through. The WAF is designed to identify a whole range of HTTP attacks, and take necessary action to keep the server safe.
You have 3 options to introduce a WAF in Azure.

Use Azure Application Gateway v2
Use Azure Front Door
Use a Marketplace WAF (will require lots of configuration)

Your best bet is to use Azure Front Door.
If your organisation already has Application Gateway or Front Door, or another WAF solution, you may wish to consult them.
It may be a bit of a learning curve, but should you wish to pursue one of these, more information can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview

Thank you! I'll consult my team if any of these options are already in use.
